# Viewport camera is different from the output rendered image

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera

[image]
viewport

[image]
output rendered

[image]

Why is the camera not in the middle? I only have camera
here is my bse file

Comment: Hello, make sure that you haven't keyframed your camera to the location that gives this render?

Comment: keyframed? I just started learning blender. Can you tell me how and where to disable the keyframed render camera?

Comment: From your screenshot, looks like your camera is inside an empty and the empty has an animation and that's probably moving the camera from it's original position, make sure to check your timeline for camera animations, other than that, you might need to show us more settings

Comment: timeline and camera animations are correct, i think something is wrong with my camera

Comment: It's hard to investigate without the file. [How to upload a blend file on BSE - good practices and advice](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3050/60486) Also, good job on the render, looks good!

Comment: Your camera is parented to an empty and this empty has keyframes on Y and Z which may create the problem? Not sure what is the problem but if you move your empty instead of scaling its scale it should work

Answer (score 2):

Non-uniform camera transformation that comes from the empty object animation messes up `Motion Blur`. It was not in the tutorial. Add a missing X Scale animation key frame for the frame 160.